# Get data from nested json in Angular

Tags: json, angular

Im trying to iterate over an array but page is displaying [ object Object] instead. How can I get data.id of my example?

Service:

```
return this._http.get<CustomersList[]>(this.apiUrl,{ headers: reqHeader });
```

My json looks like this:

```
[ {"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":25},{"id":26}] }]
```

And here is my component:

```
customerslist$: CustomersList[];
return this.customerdataService.getCustomersList().subscribe(data => this.customerslist$ = data);
```

Would be great if anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` property is an array contained in an array. You either need two `*ngFor` directives

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let customer of customerslist$">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of customer.data">
    {{ item.id }}
 </ng-container>
/ng-container>
```

Or if you're sure the `customerslist$` array will always contain only one element, you could access the first element directly.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of customerslist$[0].data">
  {{ item.id }}
</ng-container>
```

---

Also if you're aren't using the `this.customerList$` in the controller, you could skip the subscription in the controller and use the `async` pipe in the template. It takes care of any potential memory leak issues due to open subscriptions.

Contoller

```js
customerslist$: Observable<CustomersList[]>;   // <-- typeof `Observable`

ngOnInit() {
  this.customerslist$ = this.customerdataService.getCustomersList();     // <-- don't subscribe yet
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(customerslist$ | async) as customerslist">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let customer of customerslist">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of customer.data">
      {{ item.id }}
   </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

<sup>By convention, variable names suffixed with a dollar sign (`customerlist$`) are used to denote observables.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Observable `$` sign at the end of variable denotes observable,
in that case you do not need to subscribe only return value, in template you can subscribe using `async` pipe which automatically unsubscribe as well to prevent memory leak and a **recommended** approach.

Here we assume we are only taking first element of array that why directly accessing it giving first index, otherwise we need to iterate that array in template as well.

```
customerslist$: Observable<CustomersList[]>;
this.customerslist$ = this.customerdataService.getCustomersList()
 .pipe(map(res) => res[0].data));
```

In template use `async` pipe to subscribe

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of customerslist$ | async">
 <span> {{ data.id }} </span>
</ng-container>
```

**WITHOUT OBSERVABLE**

```
customerslist: CustomersList[];
this.customerdataService.getCustomersList()
 .subscribe((res) => this.customerslist = res[0].data));
```

In template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of customerslist">
 <span> {{ data.id }} </span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: `res.data` in the `map` would be undefined. `res` is an array, not an object.

Comment: thanks so much!  I tried with pipe before, but not working. Told me Observable<Unknown> is missing. I would like to use only one ngFor. Some more ideas I am doing wrong?

Comment: @SaschaK using pipe is recommended approach you can checkout my answer I updated you need to use `pipe` and `map` and return result see above first Observable approach